# Java ArrayList indexOf returns -1

Tags: java, arraylist, equals, indexof

I have a strange problem with my code.

Heres the code I test the Chunk class with:

```
List<Chunk> chunks = new ArrayList<Chunk>();
chunks.add(new Chunk(1,1,1));
System.out.println(chunks.indexOf(new Vector3i(1, 1, 1)));
```

And here is the Chunk class' equals method:

```
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    System.out.println("Test _1_");
    if (object != null && object instanceof Vector3i) {
        System.out.println("Test _2_");
        if((this.x == ((Vector3i) object).x)&&(this.y == ((Vector3i) object).y)&&(this.z == ((Vector3i) object).z)) {
            System.out.println("Test _3_");
            return true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Test _4_");

    return false;
}
```

The Vector3i:

```
public class Vector3i {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int z;


    public Vector3i(int x, int y, int z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

}
```

When I run it, it just returns -1. The test prints from the equals method doesn't print, which means that it's not even begin executed. Why is that?

Comment: This is a serious abuse of the [`Object.equals()` contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-). Your `equals()` method isn't **reflexive**, **symmetric** or **transitive**. Use a `Map<Vector3i,Chunk>` instead to associate a unique chunk with a given vector value.

Comment: You have a class named `Chunk` with an `equals` method that checks if the argument is some other type?

Comment: @MadConan It's because chunk contains lots of data, and it would be too heavy if I should compare it with a new one.

Comment: @KaareZ This is what maps are for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the [`ArrayList.indexOf`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#310) implementation, you will see that `Vector3i.equals` is called in your case. Actually it's even specified in JavaDoc for [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29):

> More formally, returns the lowest index i such that `(o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i)))`, or `-1` if there is no such index.

In general [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) operation must be symmetric: `a.equals(b) == b.equals(a)`. So you have to implement `Vector3i.equals` as well.

Please note also that your current `equals` implementation lacks other properties like reflexivity. Also consider implementing the `hashCode` when you implement an `equals`.

Comment: While this is 100% true, it is also terrible advice. For a start, you've just broken the `Object.hashCode()` contract, so I'm expecting a "Why does my `HashMap.get()` return `null`?" question soon. Secondly, it still doesn't make `equals()` reflexive.

Comment: @biziclop, well, when I say "implement equals", it's implied that it's a good idea to implement the `hashCode` as well. As for other `equals()` properties (reflexivity, transitivity, consistency), it's well written in the linked JavaDoc. Well, I'll add a notice to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
chunks.indexOf(new Vector3i(1, 1, 1)
```

calls equals() method on Vector3i class, howeve, not on Chunk class...